# AAPT getting locked

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'll do my best to explain here. I have an eclipse plugin I'm developing for android development. It's based off the Java Bridge from Google/MIT's App Inventor library. The plugin simply adds a new project wizard (which copies over a couple of jars, along with some other files, and modifies the project.properties file). It also includes a wizard to easily create a new app widget.

For the new project wizard, I essentially just copied AdtPlugin, and changed the references to AltBridge, and removed stuff which I wasn't going to need. This worked fine from r15-r16. However, I recently updated to the newest adt (r19), and did something stupid. I went and made modifications on my plugin activator class to match the changes with the new adt version. The really stupid thing is I didn't back up my files beforehand.

Anyways, the problem I'm now having is that the R file isn't getting generated after the wizard completes. If I exit eclipse, then restart it, then clean the project, the R file gets generated, and errors go away.

Also, if I use the new widget wizard, it creates the xml files fine, but then I get an error in the console saying that aapt cannot be found. A restart of eclipse fixes this.

If you'd like to see some code, let me know. As the activator class is quite large, I didn't want to post the whole thing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. In the start(BundleContext context method, it was parsing the SDK. As the adtplugin does this, it was causing a conflict on multiple levels.